# Property not found then found after loading an object of type in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This is happening in both my flask app (on a route) and when i test it using flask shell, as seen below. In terms of my model, people have a single company they are a part of (via an company_id on the person table)

```
In [3]: from model import Company, Person

In [4]: from sqlalchemy import text, func

In [5]: companies_and_total = db.session.query(Company, func.count(Company.people).label("total")).join(Person).group_by(Company.id).order_by(Company.failure_count.asc().nullsfirst(), Company.crawled_at.asc().nullsfirst(), text("total DESC")).limit(100)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-144cc8b9138c> in <module>
----> 1 companies_and_total = db.session.query(Company, func.count(Company.people).label("total")).join(Person).group_by(Company.id).order_by(Company.failure_count.asc().nullsfirst(), Company.crawled_at.asc().nullsfirst(), text("total DESC")).limit(100)

AttributeError: type object 'Company' has no attribute 'people'

In [6]: c = db.session.query(Company).first()

In [7]: c.people
Out[7]: []

In [8]: companies_and_total = db.session.query(Company, func.count(Company.people).label("total")).join(Person).group_by(Company.id).order_by(Company.failure_count.asc().nullsfirst(), Company.crawled_at.asc().nullsfirst(), text("total DESC")).limit(100)

In [9]: for c, t in companies_and_total:
   ...:     print(c)
   ...:     print("\t{}".format(t))
   ...:
Added At:2019-04-04, Name:XXX
    1798
Added At:2019-04-03, Name:XX
    657
Added At:2019-04-04, Name:XXXX
    578
```

My Model:

```
class Person(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("companies.id"))
    company = relationship("Company", backref="people")

class Company(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

Comment: Is `Company.people` defined as a backref from some other model? Please include the models in question.

Comment: Updated to include the model - yes it is defined as a backref